# Find the value of radio button checked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this table containing 3 radio buttons, I want to find out whether a particular radio button is check or not at given point of time.

```
<table align="center" width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="compareRadio" value="all" checked="checked"/>
                <label>View All Records</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="compareRadio" value="diff" />
                <label>View Differences</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="compareRadio" id="patch" value="patches" />
                <label>Compare Patches</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Export Into Excel"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I send a request to the server, when the result comes back I want to identify whether `patches` radio button is selected or not.

So I did something like this.. but it returns `all` radio button

```
$.post("/csm/compare.action",
  { 
    sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
    compareCategory: "system",
    compareSubCategory:"patch",
    xml1:absP[0],
    xml2:absP[1]},
      function(resdata)
      {
        comparePatchData=resdata;
        comparePatchLoading=false;
        if($("input:radio[name=compareRadio]").val()=="patches")
        {
            //Trigger click on radio button for "same" campare
            $('input[name=compareRadio]:eq(2)').click();  //so that it refreshes the content
            $("input[name=compareRadio]:eq(2)").attr("checked", true);
            $('input[type="radio"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
      }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to know if it is checked or not, then you could do this:

```
if($('#patch:checked').length)
    // It is checked.
```

Or:

```
if($('input[value=patches]:checked').length)
    // It is checked.
```

The `$()` function returns an array of matched elements so you can check its `length` property to see how many things (if any) were matched.

References:

- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
- [Attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: I tried `$("input:radio[name=compareRadio]:checked").val()` from [this site](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/checking-if-certain-radiobutton-is-checked) it worked for me. Thanks for your answer and explanation too.

Comment: @Abhishek: You'd use something like that if you want the value of the checked radio button and then you can see if it is the one you want. Which approach you take depends on which one more closely matches your intent: do you want to know if a specific one is checked or do you want to know which one is checked? The `#patch:checked` would probably be the quickest though, ID selectors end up as a call to `document.getElementById()` and that's pretty quick; OTOH, I doubt this will be a performance bottleneck so how fast it is doesn't matter that much.

Answer (score 1):

To find out if particular checkbox is checked you can use jQuery's [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
if($('input[value=all]').is(':checked'))
{
   //Yep, it's checked
}
```